# Handle errors without ternary operator in React Native

Tags: react-native

Within my app I get error messages from my api, these are then saved into state `const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})`.

In my view I am rendering my error alert using a ternary operator, but this is leaving some of the alert left in view when closing (because of the '' in the falsey return, I suspect). I don't want this of course.

My errors object will look something like this: `{"errors": {"newBookingError": "Something Went Wrong - Please Try Again"}}`.

```
{'newBookingError' in errors ? (
  <ErrorAlert
    errors={errors}
    showError={showError}
    handleShowErrors={handleShowErrors}
  />
) : (
  ''
)}
```

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the ternary operation you can simply use `&&`:

```
{'newBookingError' in errors && (
  <ErrorAlert
    errors={errors}
    showError={showError}
    handleShowErrors={handleShowErrors}
  />
)}
```

This simply evaluates to `false` if the condition is not met.

You can also use `null` instead of an empty string as part of the ternary operation.